# Schnakenberg-Turing paralell code in Matlab

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I'm new in paralell programming, so I adquired a GPU and a CPU in order to complete my research in the Schnakenberg model. I have the next code but I just don't know how to start to parallelize the code. It runs perfectly in MATLAB and I want to continue running the program for smaller values on the meshgrid:

```
%Solve a Turing model system of equations in 2-D space over time. Apply
%Euler’s Method to a semi-discretized Reaction-Diffusion system.
%clear all
%Grid size
Tf=1000000;
a=-1; % Lower boundary
b=1; % Upper boundary
M=50; % M is the number of spaces between points a and b.
dx=0.04; %(b-a)/M; % dx is delta x
dy=0.04; %(b-a)/M;
x=linspace(a,b,M+1); % M+1 equally spaced x vectors including a and b.
y=linspace(a,b,M+1);
%Time stepping
dt=0.08; %100*(dx^2)/2; % dt is delta t the time step
N=Tf/dt; % N is the number of time steps in the interval [0,1]
%Constant Values
D=0.516; % D is the Diffusion coefficient Du/Dv
delta=0.0021; % sizes the domain for particular wavelengths
alpha=0.899; % a is alpha, a coefficient in f and g (-a is gamma)
beta=-0.91; % b is beta, another coefficient in f and g
r1=3.5; % r1 is the cubic term
r2=0; % r2 is the quadratic term
gamma=-alpha; % g is for gamma
%pre-allocation
unp1=zeros(M+3,M+3);
vnp1=zeros(M+3,M+3);
%Initial Conditions
un=-0.5+rand(M+3,M+3); %Begin with a random point between [-0.5,0.5]
vn=-0.5+rand(M+3,M+3);
for n=1:N
for i=2:M+2
un(i,1)=un(i,3); %Boundary conditions on left flux is zero
un(i,M+3)=un(i,M+1); %Boundary conditions on right
vn(i,1)=vn(i,3);
vn(i,M+3)=vn(i,M+1);
end
for j=2:M+2
un(1,j)=un(3,j); %Boundary conditions on left
un(M+3,j)=un(M+1,j); %Boundary conditions on right
vn(1,j)=vn(3,j);
vn(M+3,j)=vn(M+1,j);
end
for i=2:M+2
for j=2:M+2
%Source function for u and v
srcu=alpha*un(i,j)*(1-r1*vn(i,j)^2)+vn(i,j)*(1-r2*un(i,j));
srcv=beta*vn(i,j)*(1+(alpha*r1/beta)*un(i,j)*vn(i,j))+un(i,j)*(gamma+r2*vn(i,j));
uxx=(un(i-1,j)-2*un(i,j)+un(i+1,j))/dx^2; %Laplacian u
vxx=(vn(i-1,j)-2*vn(i,j)+vn(i+1,j))/dx^2; %Laplacian v
uyy=(un(i,j-1)-2*un(i,j)+un(i,j+1))/dy^2; %Laplacian u
vyy=(vn(i,j-1)-2*vn(i,j)+vn(i,j+1))/dy^2; %Laplacian v
Lapu=uxx+uyy;
Lapv=vxx+vyy;
unp1(i,j)=un(i,j)+dt*(D*delta*Lapu+srcu);
vnp1(i,j)=vn(i,j)+dt*(delta*Lapv+srcv);
end
end
un=unp1;
vn=vnp1;
% Graphing
if mod(n,6250)==0
%subplot(2,1,2)
hdl = surf(x,y,un(2:M+2,2:M+2));
set(hdl,'edgecolor','none');
axis([ -1, 1,-1,1]);
%caxis([-10,15]);
view(2);
colorbar;
fprintf('Time t = %f\n',n*dt);
ch = input('Hit enter to continue :','s');
if (strcmp(ch,'k') == 1)
keyboard;
end
end
end
```

So the big question is there somebody who can help me to order the code and send the job to the workers in the GPU in order to reduce time of excecution and obtain the frame for big times and very small steps in the Euler's method. I mean, how the code would be separated in order to use **parfor** and all those sentences in parallel programming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to vectorize your code first and you will see dramatic improvemenets in speed even without a GPU. Once properly vectorized, running it on the GPU will be easy.

Since your outer loop over n contains an evolution over time and depends on the previous results, you cannot vectorize that. But all the inner for loops you can do away with:

Instead of

```
for i=2:M+2
    un(i,1)=un(i,3); %Boundary conditions on left flux is zero
    un(i,M+3)=un(i,M+1); %Boundary conditions on right
    vn(i,1)=vn(i,3);
    vn(i,M+3)=vn(i,M+1);
end
```

use:

```
i=2:M+2
un(i,1)=un(i,3); %Boundary conditions on left flux is zero
un(i,M+3)=un(i,M+1); %Boundary conditions on right
vn(i,1)=vn(i,3);
vn(i,M+3)=vn(i,M+1);
```

likewise you can replace the double for loop with:

```
i=2:M+2;
j=2:M+2;
srcu=alpha*un(i,j).*(1-r1*vn(i,j)^2)+vn(i,j).*(1-r2*un(i,j));
srcv=beta*vn(i,j).*(1+(alpha*r1/beta)*un(i,j).*vn(i,j))+un(i,j).*(gamma+r2*vn(i,j));
uxx=(un(i-1,j)-2*un(i,j)+un(i+1,j))/dx^2; %Laplacian u
vxx=(vn(i-1,j)-2*vn(i,j)+vn(i+1,j))/dx^2; %Laplacian v
uyy=(un(i,j-1)-2*un(i,j)+un(i,j+1))/dy^2; %Laplacian u
vyy=(vn(i,j-1)-2*vn(i,j)+vn(i,j+1))/dy^2; %Laplacian v
```

Note that this looks very similar to what you coded originally, but that the 'for' statements are gone and that I replaced the "*" with ".*" in some instances, which indicates elementwise operations on the whole matrix, e.g. matlab can compute

```
un(i,j).*(1-r1*vn(i,j)^2)
```

for the whole index list in i and j MUCH faster than when you go through an explicit loop.

If you implement your function this way, it should run already faster on the CPU. Since inside your main loop you are now only carrying out element wise operations on matrices, its trivial to port it to GPU, by casting all the variables you use inside the loop as gpuArrays and use 'gather' to get the results back to the CPU.

Comment: can you help me with de complete code?